# How can I enroll a device to a group enrollment in Azure IOT hub?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have seen code for individual enrollment but I can't find any for group enrollment. I need to bulk enroll a thousand devices to Azure IOT Hub and was thinking of group enrollment.Any sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible both with group enrollment and bulk individual enrollments. From the [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/provisioning/service/samples) related to [How to manage device enrollments with Azure Device Provisioning Service SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-manage-enrollments-sdks):

**Bulk Individual Enrollments**

```
public async Task<List<IndividualEnrollment>> CreateBulkIndividualEnrollmentsAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new set of individualEnrollments...");

    List<IndividualEnrollment> individualEnrollments = new List<IndividualEnrollment>();

    foreach (var item in _registrationIds)
    {
        Attestation attestation = new TpmAttestation(item.Value);

        individualEnrollments.Add(new IndividualEnrollment(item.Key, attestation));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nRunning the bulk operation to create the individualEnrollments...");

    BulkEnrollmentOperationResult bulkEnrollmentOperationResult =

    await _provisioningServiceClient.RunBulkEnrollmentOperationAsync(BulkOperationMode.Create, individualEnrollments).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.WriteLine("\nResult of the Create bulk enrollment.");

    Console.WriteLine(bulkEnrollmentOperationResult);

    return individualEnrollments;
}
```

**Create Enrollment Group**

```
public async Task CreateEnrollmentGroupAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new enrollmentGroup...");

    Attestation attestation = X509Attestation.CreateFromRootCertificates(_groupIssuerCertificate);

    EnrollmentGroup enrollmentGroup =
        new EnrollmentGroup(
            EnrollmentGroupId,
            attestation);

    Console.WriteLine(enrollmentGroup);

    Console.WriteLine("\nAdding new enrollmentGroup...");

    EnrollmentGroup enrollmentGroupResult =
        await _provisioningServiceClient.CreateOrUpdateEnrollmentGroupAsync(enrollmentGroup).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.WriteLine("\nEnrollmentGroup created with success.");

    Console.WriteLine(enrollmentGroupResult);
}
```

**Update**

Take a look at the [device](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/provisioning/Samples/device) samples. You don't need to specify the enrollment type (individual/group) when registering the device. the correlation to the defined enrollment in the portal is done using the certificate the device uses when it registers.

**Update 2**

See [Quickstart: Control a device connected to an IoT hub (.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device-dotnet) to see how to communicate with a device that was already enrolled to **IoT Hub**

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried this and I was able to create a enrollment group using the second part of the code. How can I add devices to the group enrollment? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: But in Group Enrollment I wont be able to use TPM attestation right? I am fairly new to this  and I am under the impression that for group enrollment we don't need to enroll a device but create a device with the certification specified for group enrollment. And while running the device it will get enrolled. Correct me if I am wrong. So can you share a code where a device is created using a X509 attestation and added to group enrollment.

Comment: Take a look at [X509Sample\Program.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/provisioning/Samples/device/X509Sample/Program.cs) and [Common\ProvisioningDeviceClientSample.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/provisioning/Samples/device/Common/ProvisioningDeviceClientSample.cs) to see how it can be done (their part of the device samples I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: So I have created a group enrollment and added a sample device. So no I can communicate with that? Shouldnt I need the device connection string to do so? Also how can add another device to the group using the same X509 certificate. Do I need to create once for each device?

Comment: I think you need an additional certificate derived from the same root certificate or intermediate certificate (see [Enrollment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-manage-enrollments-sdks#create-a-device-enrollment)). On how to control a connected device, see second update.