# Enrolling multiple device using Group Enrollment in Azure Device Provisioning Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

There is a lack of documentation when it comes to Group Enrollment in Azure Device Provisioning Service. I was able to create a Enrollment Group and enroll a device to that following these document
[test X509 certificate creation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md) and [Simulate a device by giving the idscope of the device](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-x509-csharp.md)

And right now I have a device registered in Group enrollment and linked to my IOT hub.
But I have some questions

1. How can we enroll multiple devices to the Group Enrollment using the test 
   certificate created? Or do we need multiple certificates too?
2. Do we need to register the device after enrolling in Group enrollment?
3. How can we get the connection string for device while provisioning in a 
   group enrollment?

   If anyone can provide an answer would be greatly helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enroll a device to a group enrollment in Azure IOT hub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845505/how-can-i-enroll-a-device-to-a-group-enrollment-in-azure-iot-hub)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to your other question here for better understanding of client side authentication. [Using same X509 certificate for multiple devices in Azure device provisioning service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946286/using-same-x509-certificate-for-multiple-devices-in-azure-device-provisioning-se)

Answers to your above questions:

1- You need unique certificate and private key for each device to provision it on IoTHub.

2- Same enrollment group can be used to provision as many devices as you want.

3- Connection String is not needed with X.509 authentication. Connection String is used to generate SAS tokens which is symmetric keys method of authentication. You are not using symmetric keys auth in this case.